# Android - How to join two Bitmaps of same width vertically?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-view, android-bitmap

I have a layout, the upper half of which is a google map, and the lower half having some data. I need to programmatically take a screenshot of the entire screen. I am taking screenshot of both half views and want to join them vertically. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: A lot more detail needed!  Is there a particular software package or language you're seeking to do this in?  What have you already tried?

Comment: i want screenshot of complete layout containing google map on upper half of layout and linear layout with some textview on bottom. i am doing this in android

Comment: I'd update your question to reflect that, I was moderating and tripped across it under triage.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I think what you're trying to ask is a "valid" SO question, but I don't think anyone will be able to determine what you're asking with how it is written.  Be verbose, include a screenshot and a mock-up (if applicable), and link some examples or articles which show what research you've done and indicate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: hey i am doing this in android programming. i have two screenshot and want to join them vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to join two bitmaps vertically (or horizontally for that matter). It can be done in the following manner.

Say you have two views, `view1` and `view2`. You first need to create *three* bitmaps for these two views like this:

```
int a = view1.getMeasuredWidth();
int b = view1.getMeasuredHeight();
int c = view2.getMeasuredWidth();
int d = view2.getMeasuredHeight();

Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(a, b, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(c, d, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap b3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(a, b + d, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The third bitmap `b3` will contain the vertically merged bitmaps `b1` and `b2` as required. To merge them, do as follows:

```
Canvas c1 = new Canvas(b1);
view1.draw(c1);

Canvas c2 = new Canvas(b2);
view2.draw(c2);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b3);

canvas.drawBitmap(b2, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(b1, 0, view2.getHeight(), null);
```

Now `b3` should have what you want.

Try this. This will work.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but i already have bitmap of both view i just want to join them vertically

Comment: Have you tried this approach ? It will do what you want. It works for me. It merges the two bitmaps into a single one. Please try it first ... :)